# Add View Above All ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm making an app where a user can play music. I would like to add a view to the bottom of the screen that shows what song is playing. Like Apple's Music app.

[image: Example based off of the Apple Music app]

I would like the view to be on all of my app's `ViewControllers` except detail view controllers. I know how to add a view to the window, simply...

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let view = UIView()

    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.insertSubview(view, at: 0)
    window?.bringSubview(toFront: view)

    return true
}
```

But, I would really like to be able to design the view, not programmatically, but in the storyboard. Therefore, I would need a `UIViewController` to act as this view. How do I add this `UIViewController` (let's just say the height is 70) to the bottom of all my views? Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Programmatically or not, you need to learn the difference between view controllers and views (or more technically, between `UIViewControllers` and `UIViews`). You *do not* add a view controller to a view - it's not possible - but you can add a view to a view controller's view (and a view controller to a view controller). That's called *hierarchy*... parent-child. Finally, **none** of this has anything to do with code *or* storyboard, as in they can happen either way. So what exactly are you trying to do? Make a view be floating above the remaining views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create a `UIViewController` , you can Create a custom `UIView` with Xib file and load it as a `UIView` , then add it to the window

```
let customView = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("hoverView", owner: self, options: nil))?[0] as! hoverView;

customView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: w , height: h )

// then add it anywhere
```

Comment: Oh! That's a good idea. I forgot about Xib files! I'm new to coding. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Sh_Khan what happen if this view is overlapping the view behind it?

Comment: use insertSubview to insert it above any view you want

Comment: insertSubview is for a specific view, but as per requirement it needs for all application, not for a specific view.

Comment: actually he needs that overlap floating view